# static information in a class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I would like a couple of my classes to have a way of telling me how many fields are in them, and I would like to enforce that all my classes have this through inheritance, like this:

```
// this code does not compile
abstract class Base
{
    abstract static const int FieldCount = -1
}

class Node : Base
{
    int x, y, z; // has three fields, so:
    override static const int FieldCount = 3;
}

class Way : Base
{
    int w, x, y, z; // has four fields, so:
    override static const int FieldCount = 4;
}
```

I cannot get it to working, not with an interface or an abstract base class. I need this information to be available just with the type, not through an actual instance of the class (therefore static).

```
class EnumerableDataReader<TSource> : IDataReader where TSource : Base {
    public int FieldCount {
        get {
            return TSource.FieldCount <- access the static info, does not work
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do that, or would here Reflection be the only way to go?

Thanks!

Comment: Of course reflection would be the way to go -- otherwise what would stop you from reporting the wrong number even if there was a way to make the syntax work?

Comment: You can't use polymorphism for static members. You can use `override` only for Methods, events, and properties only. not with `Fields` or `Constants`

Comment: @James even when Op changes to Property too this won't work. since member is **static**

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yeah noticed there are more issues than just compilation problems!

Comment: `static` and "inheritance" don't go together. In fact, `static` and OO don't work together. (Not in the C++/Java/C# model.)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like there is any real need to use fields specifically here, if you switched to using properties instead you could override the property implementation on each derivation i.e.

```
abstract class Base
{
    public static int FieldCount { get { return -1; } }
}

class Node : Base
{
    int x, y, z; // has three fields, so:
    public new static int FieldCount { get { return 3; } }
}

class Way : Base
{
    int w, x, y, z; // has four fields, so:
    public new static int FieldCount { get { return 4; } }
}
...
Console.WriteLine(Base.FieldCount) // -1
Console.WriteLine(Node.FieldCount) // 3
Console.WriteLine(Way.FieldCount) // 4
```

To solve the other half of your problem, you will need to rely on Reflection i.e.

```
class EnumerableDataReader<TSource> where TSource : Base
{
    public int FieldCount
    {
        get {
            return (int)typeof(TSource).GetProperties().Single(x => x.Name == "FieldCount").GetValue(null);
        }
    }
}
...
var reader = new EnumerableDataReader<Node>();
Console.WriteLine(reader.FieldCount); // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Static members do not support virtual inheritance because virtual inheritance is about resolving a member given an instance. Static members do not exist on instances.

You can use reflection to read static members given a type parameter or a `Type` instance.

There is a lot of "magic" in your design. A new developer might not immediately pick up the convention of having a specially named field. I'd consider changing the design to a **custom attribute** on your `TSource` types.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a separate static class to store the field count or any type-specific data.  Static fields in a static class are unique per-type, meaning that MyStaticClass.FieldCount is a separate variable from MyStaticClass.FieldCount.

Additionally, you can use the static constructor to set the value the first type the class is touched.

For example,

```
public static class FieldCountStatic<T>
{
    public static int FieldCount { get; set; }
}

class Node
{
    static Node()
    {
        FieldCountStatic<Node>.FieldCount = 3;
    }

    int x, y, z;
}

class Way
{
    static Way()
    {
        FieldCountStatic<Way>.FieldCount = 4;
    }

    int w, x, y, z; // has four fields

}

class EnumerableDataReader<TSource> : IDataReader
{
    public int FieldCount
    {
        get
        {
            return FieldCountStatic<TSource>.FieldCount;
        }
    }
}
```